# deploy war in jetty without web.xml

Tags: java, spring-boot, jetty, war, jetty-9

I'm trying to deploy a simple spring boot application as war into jetty (9.4.30).
Copying the *test.war* into the */webapps* directory the application is started as expected. 
But when I run an embedded jetty I only get see the content of the war in the browser.

How should I deploy the war file in the embedded jetty?

[image]

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Server server = new Server(80);

        HandlerCollection handlers = new HandlerCollection();

        WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
        context.setContextPath("/test");
        context.setWarResource(
                Resource.newResource(new File("/test.war")));
        handlers.addHandler(context);
        server.setHandler(handlers);

        server.start();
        System.out.println("Started!");
        server.join();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: sorry didn't find a solution